# Objective-C: Associative Object Behaviors

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime, associative

Does `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC` of the [Associative Object Behaviors](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Associative_Object_Behaviors) in the [Objective-C Runtime Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html), call `release` on the old value referenced by the associated object before it assigns & retains the new value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. If you use the retain or copy behaviors when associating the value, then that value will be released when either a new value is associated (regardless of the behavior attached to the new value), or the object itself is deallocated.